# Update function not working in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

currently I'm develop a system using VB.NET. I have the following query for UPDATE. This query is work when I run in SQL Developer

```
UPDATE CCS2_TBL_INSPECTION_STANDARD SET CCSEQREVITEM = :CCSEQREVITEM, 
CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = TO_DATE(:CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') WHERE CCSEQID 
= :CCSEQID
```

But when I try applied this query in VB.net, its not work. Actually the flow for this update function is work but when I update the data, it is not working. For example, I want update name from 'Ali' to 'Abu', when I click the update button, there popup windows says that "Update success" but the name is not change to 'Abu', it still 'Ali'. There no error when I execute. Anyone know? Below VB.net code:

```
Protected Sub editInspectionRev(eqid As String)

    Dim xSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    xSQL.AppendLine("UPDATE CCS2_TBL_INSPECTION_STANDARD")
    xSQL.AppendLine("SET")
    xSQL.AppendLine("CCSEQREVITEM = :CCSEQREVITEM, CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = TO_DATE(:CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')")
    xSQL.AppendLine("WHERE CCSEQID = :CCSEQID")

    Using cn As New OracleConnection(ConString)
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(xSQL.ToString, cn)
        cmd.Connection = cn


        cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQREVITEM", txtRevContent.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE", txtRevEffDate.Text)


        cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQID", eqid)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

    End Using
    success3.Visible = True
    DisplayRevisionDetails()

End Sub
```

Comment: When you call `ExecuteNonQuery` there are three possible outcomes. The call may succeed and return zero, meaning that there were no records that matched your criteria so no changes were made. The call may succeed and return a non-zero value, meaning that that many records were affected by the command.  The call may fail and throw an exception.  Which is it in your case?  This is the sort of information you need to gather before posting here.  If you haven't looked for that information then you haven't tried to fix the issue, which means you shouldn't be posting here.

Comment: The other update function in my system is working well. But only this update is not working well. I tried compare with other, it same. But I don't know why it is not work.

Comment: What other methods are doing is irrelevant. If this one was actually the same as another then one would have to wonder why you have both instead of just one. Obviously it's not the same or, at least, not used the same or it would be behaving the same. You don't fix issues in code simply by reading the code. You debug it. Now, how about answering the question I asked?  It wasn't rhetorical.

Comment: Relax okay. I'm still new in VB.net.

Comment: That's fine but if you're going to ask for help and someone requests more information in order to provide that help and you don't bother to you don't provide it then you're wasting everyone's time.  That's not a concept specific to VB.NET so it's not subject to your newness.

Comment: When you pass your connection as a parameter to your command's constructor you do not need to set the command's connection property. That is not your problem, it is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQREVITEM", txtRevContent.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE", txtRevEffDate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQID", eqid)
```

This code is incorrect. You are not getting a compile error because there is a deprecated .Add method that takes a string and an object. This has been replaced by .Add that takes a string and a database data type. What you are probably looking for is .AddWithValue which is probably what was used in the other update Function.

Back to the .Add method. The first parameter is the name of the parameter. The second is the DataType of the parameter and the third is the size. There may be an overload without the size. Then the .Value property is set.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQREVITEM", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = txtRevContent.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE",OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value =  txtRevEffDate.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(":CCSEQID", OracleType.Int32).Value = eqid
```

Comment: Thanks, but it say " AddWithValue is not a member of 'Oracle.DataAcces.Client.OracleParameterCollection' "

Comment: So sorry, I am used to SQL Server.

Comment: Try a different overload of .Add in my corrected answer.

Comment: I guessed at the Oracle data types and sizes (for the VarChars). If they don't match your table then you need to adjust the code. Are you getting any errors or is the table just failing to update?